# How to fix bootstrap carousel bug?

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, carousel, visual-web-developer

The last item of the carousel is not showing up properly and breaks the carousel itself. But when i comment out the third item of carousel, it looks nice without eventough, there is no last item in carousel. How can i fix this bug? All the necessary things have been linked such as bootstrap, jQuery and font-awesome.

```
<div id="carouselServices" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md px-md-5">
                                        <div class="text-dark pb-3">
                                            <i class="fa fa-shield fa-5x"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <h4 class="text-dark">WPWL MULTI-LANGUAGE SUPPORT</h4>
                                        <br>
                                        <p class="text-secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro quam iure suscipit minus, ab, distinctio ex voluptatibus, dolorum quisquam incidunt dolores. Atque, eos sit. Fuga, reiciendis? Maiores rerum deleniti illo!</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md px-md-5">
                                        <div class="text-dark pb-3">
                                            <i class="fa fa-cog fa-5x"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <h4 class="text-dark">FULLY CUSTOMIZABLE THEME</h4>
                                        <br>
                                        <p class="text-secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro quam iure suscipit minus, ab, distinctio ex voluptatibus, dolorum quisquam incidunt dolores. Atque, eos sit. Fuga, reiciendis? Maiores rerum deleniti illo!</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md px-md-5">
                                        <div class="text-dark pb-3">
                                            <i class="fa fa-bolt fa-5x"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <h4 class="text-dark">STUNNING UPDATE VERSION 7.0</h4>
                                        <br>
                                        <p class="text-secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro quam iure suscipit minus, ab, distinctio ex voluptatibus, dolorum quisquam incidunt dolores. Atque, eos sit. Fuga, reiciendis? Maiores rerum deleniti illo!</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md px-md-5">
                                        <div class="text-dark pb-3">
                                            <i class="fa fa-shield fa-5x"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <h4 class="text-dark">WPWL MULTI-LANGUAGE SUPPORT</h4>
                                        <br>
                                        <p class="text-secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro quam iure suscipit minus, ab, distinctio ex voluptatibus, dolorum quisquam incidunt dolores. Atque, eos sit. Fuga, reiciendis? Maiores rerum deleniti illo!</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md px-md-5">
                                        <div class="text-dark pb-3">
                                            <i class="fa fa-cog fa-5x"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <h4 class="text-dark">FULLY CUSTOMIZABLE THEME</h4>
                                        <br>
                                        <p class="text-secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro quam iure suscipit minus, ab, distinctio ex voluptatibus, dolorum quisquam incidunt dolores. Atque, eos sit. Fuga, reiciendis? Maiores rerum deleniti illo!</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md px-md-5">
                                        <div class="text-dark pb-3">
                                            <i class="fa fa-bolt fa-5x"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <h4 class="text-dark">STUNNING UPDATE VERSION 7.0</h4>
                                        <br>
                                        <p class="text-secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro quam iure suscipit minus, ab, distinctio ex voluptatibus, dolorum quisquam incidunt dolores. Atque, eos sit. Fuga, reiciendis? Maiores rerum deleniti illo!</p>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md px-md-5">
                                        <div class="text-dark pb-3">
                                            <i class="fa fa-shield fa-5x"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <h4 class="text-dark">WPWL MULTI-LANGUAGE SUPPORT</h4>
                                        <br>
                                        <p class="text-secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro quam iure suscipit minus, ab, distinctio ex voluptatibus, dolorum quisquam incidunt dolores. Atque, eos sit. Fuga, reiciendis? Maiores rerum deleniti illo!</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md px-md-5">
                                        <div class="text-dark pb-3">
                                            <i class="fa fa-cog fa-5x"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <h4 class="text-dark">FULLY CUSTOMIZABLE THEME</h4>
                                        <br>
                                        <p class="text-secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro quam iure suscipit minus, ab, distinctio ex voluptatibus, dolorum quisquam incidunt dolores. Atque, eos sit. Fuga, reiciendis? Maiores rerum deleniti illo!</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md px-md-5">
                                        <div class="text-dark pb-3">
                                            <i class="fa fa-bolt fa-5x"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <h4 class="text-dark">STUNNING UPDATE VERSION 7.0</h4>
                                        <br>
                                        <p class="text-secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro quam iure suscipit minus, ab, distinctio ex voluptatibus, dolorum quisquam incidunt dolores. Atque, eos sit. Fuga, reiciendis? Maiores rerum deleniti illo!</p>
                                    </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#carouselServices" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carouselServices" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carouselServices" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <a href="#carouselServices" class="carousel-control-prev" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#carouselServices" class="carousel-control-next" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all move your `carousel-indicators` , `carousel-control-prev` and `carousel-control-next` elements outside the carousel-inner div element. Also one of your `carousel-item` div is not closed. I have made some changes to the code, please check if it works now

```
<div id="carouselServices" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#carouselServices" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carouselServices" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carouselServices" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md px-md-5">
                                    <div class="text-dark pb-3">
                                        <i class="fa fa-shield fa-5x"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <h4 class="text-dark">WPWL MULTI-LANGUAGE SUPPORT</h4>
                                    <br>
                                    <p class="text-secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro quam iure suscipit minus, ab, distinctio ex voluptatibus, dolorum quisquam incidunt dolores. Atque, eos sit. Fuga, reiciendis? Maiores rerum deleniti illo!</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md px-md-5">
                                    <div class="text-dark pb-3">
                                        <i class="fa fa-cog fa-5x"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <h4 class="text-dark">FULLY CUSTOMIZABLE THEME</h4>
                                    <br>
                                    <p class="text-secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro quam iure suscipit minus, ab, distinctio ex voluptatibus, dolorum quisquam incidunt dolores. Atque, eos sit. Fuga, reiciendis? Maiores rerum deleniti illo!</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md px-md-5">
                                    <div class="text-dark pb-3">
                                        <i class="fa fa-bolt fa-5x"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <h4 class="text-dark">STUNNING UPDATE VERSION 7.0</h4>
                                    <br>
                                    <p class="text-secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro quam iure suscipit minus, ab, distinctio ex voluptatibus, dolorum quisquam incidunt dolores. Atque, eos sit. Fuga, reiciendis? Maiores rerum deleniti illo!</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md px-md-5">
                                    <div class="text-dark pb-3">
                                        <i class="fa fa-shield fa-5x"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <h4 class="text-dark">WPWL MULTI-LANGUAGE SUPPORT</h4>
                                    <br>
                                    <p class="text-secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro quam iure suscipit minus, ab, distinctio ex voluptatibus, dolorum quisquam incidunt dolores. Atque, eos sit. Fuga, reiciendis? Maiores rerum deleniti illo!</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md px-md-5">
                                    <div class="text-dark pb-3">
                                        <i class="fa fa-cog fa-5x"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <h4 class="text-dark">FULLY CUSTOMIZABLE THEME</h4>
                                    <br>
                                    <p class="text-secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro quam iure suscipit minus, ab, distinctio ex voluptatibus, dolorum quisquam incidunt dolores. Atque, eos sit. Fuga, reiciendis? Maiores rerum deleniti illo!</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md px-md-5">
                                    <div class="text-dark pb-3">
                                        <i class="fa fa-bolt fa-5x"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <h4 class="text-dark">STUNNING UPDATE VERSION 7.0</h4>
                                    <br>
                                    <p class="text-secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro quam iure suscipit minus, ab, distinctio ex voluptatibus, dolorum quisquam incidunt dolores. Atque, eos sit. Fuga, reiciendis? Maiores rerum deleniti illo!</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md px-md-5">
                                    <div class="text-dark pb-3">
                                        <i class="fa fa-shield fa-5x"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <h4 class="text-dark">WPWL MULTI-LANGUAGE SUPPORT</h4>
                                    <br>
                                    <p class="text-secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro quam iure suscipit minus, ab, distinctio ex voluptatibus, dolorum quisquam incidunt dolores. Atque, eos sit. Fuga, reiciendis? Maiores rerum deleniti illo!</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md px-md-5">
                                    <div class="text-dark pb-3">
                                        <i class="fa fa-cog fa-5x"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <h4 class="text-dark">FULLY CUSTOMIZABLE THEME</h4>
                                    <br>
                                    <p class="text-secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro quam iure suscipit minus, ab, distinctio ex voluptatibus, dolorum quisquam incidunt dolores. Atque, eos sit. Fuga, reiciendis? Maiores rerum deleniti illo!</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md px-md-5">
                                    <div class="text-dark pb-3">
                                        <i class="fa fa-bolt fa-5x"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <h4 class="text-dark">STUNNING UPDATE VERSION 7.0</h4>
                                    <br>
                                    <p class="text-secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro quam iure suscipit minus, ab, distinctio ex voluptatibus, dolorum quisquam incidunt dolores. Atque, eos sit. Fuga, reiciendis? Maiores rerum deleniti illo!</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- ./carousel-inner -->

                    <a href="#carouselServices" class="carousel-control-prev" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#carouselServices" class="carousel-control-next" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                </div><!-- ./carousel -->
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Happy to help !